# Celery KeyError: 'myproject.tasks.async_task'

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

When i'm trying to run celery background task then it giving me error: `KeyError: 'myproject.tasks.async_task'`

I'm using `python version: 3.8.10`, `django verion: 4.1.2` , `celery version: 5.2.7` and `rabbitmq version: 3.8.2`

here below screenshot is my project structure:

[image]

here below is my code for background task:

settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost:5672'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

myproject/**init**.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from myproject.celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os, sys
from celery import Celery
import django
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

app = Celery('myproject')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task
from time import sleep
import os

@shared_task
def sleepy(duration):
    sleep(duration)
    return None
 
@shared_task
def async_task(save_path, name_of_file):
    sleep(30)
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".html")         
    file1 = open(completeName, "w")
    toFile = 'test data'
    file1.write(toFile)
    file1.close()
    return 'task complete'
```

views.py

```
def add_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id_col_data = request.POST.getlist('services')
        target_col = request.POST.get('target_col')
        file_name = request.POST.get('file_name')
        amz_columns_dict = {'id_col': id_col_data,
                            'target_col': target_col,
                            'wt_col': None}
        import os.path
        save_path = '/home/satyajit/Desktop/'
        if os.path.exists(save_path):
            try:
                from myproject.tasks import async_task
                name_of_file = file_name
                status = async_task.delay(save_path, name_of_file)   #celery task
                print('status---->', status)
            except Exception as e:
                print('task error is ------>', e)
                return render(request,'data/error.html', {'message': 'async task error'})
        else:
            print('error occured')
        return HttpResponse('product added successfully')
    return render(request, 'add_product.html')
```

When i run this celery command `celery -A myproject worker -l info` to check the celery process work then i get below trackback.
**The traceback full details on below screenshot:**

[image]